# Nest.JS: How to properly handle query param that contains url with multiple query params?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am working with some old nest.js codebase and we have `/login` endpoint.

This endpoint is waiting for query param `redirect_url`.

`redirect_url` can contain multiple query params too like this `http://localhost:3000/api/schemas/generate?appId=application&event=eventName&registry=registry`.

And finally, we have something like this:

`http://localhost:3000/api/login?redirect_url=http://localhost:3000/api/schemas/generate?appId=application&event=eventName&registry=registry`

because it is not encoded expected that `@Query()` object is:

```json
{
  "redirect_url": "http://localhost:3000/api/schemas/generate?appId=application",
  "event": "eventName",
  "registry": "registry"
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this in nest.js and not lost query params?

```json
{
  "redirect_url": "http://localhost:3000/api/schemas/generate?appId=application&event=eventName&registry=registry"
}
```

Comment: [`new URL('Your URL here')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the redirect_url with query params first you have to encode it using encodeURIComponent and decode it in nest with decodeURIComponent. Do something like this:

```
const redirect_url = "http://localhost:3000/api/schemas/generate?appId=application";
const encoded_url = encodeURIComponent(redirect_url);
const url = `http://localhost:3000/api/login?redirect_url=${redirect_url}&event=eventName&registry=registry`
```